# Can a Hollow Mekhet have a bloodline?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

Currently, I am building a Mekhet and have chosen the Norvegi bloodline. According to the book, in order to become a Hollow Mekhet all you have to do is feed from one. I am wondering if I can have both the Norvegi bloodline, as well as be a Hollow Mehket?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the rules that says that you can't be both a Hollow Mekhet and be avused into a bloodline, so you're safe there. However, Hollow Mekhet arise from the post-mortem Embrace, rather than "just feeding from one." This shouldn't have too strong an impact on play, but it may influence your pre-game story.